# Babel is not processing Array.from or 'for ... of' loops

Tags: babeljs

I'm using babel with gulp (`.pipe($.babel())`), and it seems to work for most things but is not working for `Array.from`.

It works fine when running `babel-node`:

```
$ ./node_modules/babel/bin/babel-node.js
> Array.from
[Function: from]
```

But when the following code is processed with gulp:

```
var foo = () => { console.log(Array.from) }
```

The transpiled source is:

```
var foo = function foo() {
    console.log(Array.from);
};
```

And the console output when I execute `foo` is:

> undefined

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Ended up solving this myself while writing my question, but figured I'd finish and answer myself to help future searchers:

There are certain features of babel that require a polyfill loaded in the browser due to limitations of ES5. This is loaded automatically in `babel-node` or you can include with with [babel-polyfill](https://babeljs.io/docs/usage/polyfill/).

Some of the features requiring the polyfill:

- Abstract References
- Array destructuring
- Async functions
- Comprehensions
- For of
- Array.from
- spread

Comment: For anyone that needs to include the polyfill in the browser - if you're using the grunt-babel npm module, you can find the polyfill in node_modules/grunt-babel/node_modules/babel-core/browser-polyfill.min.js

Comment: babel's `transform-runtime` is a better option than polyfill, which pollutes global scope on an Exxon Valdez level.

Comment: @ThomasMcCabe that looks cool, and is probably the right choice in many situations, but it explicitly does not support *instance methods* like `Array.from` so not a viable solution for this question.

Comment: @ZachLysobey I don't believe this is the case any longer. I'm not using polyfill and I see my transpiled code using the correct `(0, _from2.default)(arr)` call instead of `Array.from(arr)` and the code from `core-js/modules/es6.array.from.js` is required as `_from`/`_from2` in my bundle.

Comment: The link in my answer (https://babeljs.io/docs/usage/polyfill/) still seems to indicate that you need it. I'll see if I can verify this myself when I get some time, or if you have some OSS project where I can look at the config, I'd appreciate it ;-)

Comment: Neither the polyfill nor `transform-runtime` seems to cover Array.includes(). — any suggestion for that?

Comment: @FrankNocke That is covered by the polyfill:
https://babeljs.io/docs/usage/polyfill/
"This means you can use new built-ins like Promise or WeakMap, static methods like Array.from or Object.assign, instance methods like Array.prototype.includes"